# Star Wars canon: what elements of the EU have been brought into canon between April 25, 2014 & Sept. 14, 2015?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I recently learned that the planet Nar Shaddaa has been taken from the "legends" storyline and included in the official canon via the mobile game "Star Wars: Commander". Im curious to know now, are there any other planets/characters/vehicles/lore or other major elements of the "legends" storyline now been included in canon?

Comment: @kapetanios:   I would VTC this as arbitrary.   But if the dates had some meaning, like between the Legends announcement and the release of TFA, I'd personally be okay with it.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I'll VTC as arbitrary. This is merely a *technicality* to avoid closure as a list question -- and should be recognized as such, and burninated. Like you said, if the bounds were *meaningful* it would be a different matter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a list question (the bounds are arbitrary and seem only to be there to circumvent this close reason, which is a no-no).